# Android animation on EditText like Spotify Search

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

I need an animation on `EditText`, similar to Spotify Android app's search bar. It's border expands with animation on focus.

I tried to use `ValueAnimator`, increased padding of `EditText` and decreased outer view's padding at the same time using multiple `PropertyValuesHolder` on `onAnimationUpdate`, but it seems a little laggy with this way.

Is there any better solutions for performance?

Before focus:
[image]

After focus:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Search view? It works similar as you mentioned above

Comment: @Nivedh it doesn't work with similar animation as I see. Can you provide me an example if so?